# How to use dynamic filter used between sharepoint list to add new item

Tags: list, filter, sharepoint-online

I want to insert a new element in list 2 with in ParentID the value of the ID used in the filter. If nothing is selected
on list 1, it should not be possible to add a new element in list 2.

[image]

Is there a simple way in standard to do that in sharepoint or what is the method to reach this objectif.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with SharePoint Online out of the box list forms.

Either you will have to create the the canvas app using Power Apps or customize the SharePoint list forms (for list 2) using Power Apps.

Here's what you can try:

1. Add a lookup column in list 2 which lookups the information from list 1
2. Customize the forms of list 2 using Power Apps, check: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
3. Show/hide or enable/disable all other fields in list 2 form if selection of item from list 1 is empty, you can use formula like below in general to disable the fields (set `DisplayMode` property):

```
If(
   IsBlankOrError(ComboBox1.Selected.Value),
   DisplayMode.Disabled,
   DisplayMode.Edit
)
```

4. Use similar logic for all your fields to enable/disable field until at least an item from parent list 1 is selected in respective drop down/combo box (`ComboBox1` in above example)

Comment: Thanks, i try it but in power apps i don't know how to reach the value of the filter in order to add a new item

Comment: When you add a lookup column in list 2, values from list 1 should be shown automatically in drop down (combo box control)

Comment: thanks. but if i open in power appas my list 2 in order to modify the add form is there a special variable that contain the value of the filter ? And what is name ?